# Google Analytics: Track two domains as one

Tags: google-analytics

At work we have two domains that serve the exact same website/code/etc.  I'm trying to find out if there is a way to track them through Google Analytics and have a single account that could not care less which domain it's serving analytics data for?  The issue that I have currently is that the domain that we use for advertising is showing up as a referrer which is hiding (or at least I don't know how to find) what the true source was (google/bing/yahoo/etc).

Please note...
After searching on here I just wanted to add this to hopefully make it 100% clear. I don't want to track the two domains individually...I want my GA account to merge the data without regard to what domain the users browser shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want that anyways?

Having 2 domains serve the same content could be counted as duplicate content and could screw up your google ranking. I advice to redirect one domain to the other so 1 domain actually handles the website and the other just catches visitors.

If you would like to do it anyways

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-12345-1");
pageTracker._setDomainName("none");
pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

But you also need to edit all your links, read the article below.

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503

Comment: I wish I could do that, but due to Microsoft Adcenters retarded rules I can't forward so I need the ability to do as I described

Comment: It appears through reading the link that you posted that I'd need a different script for each domain in order to set the `_setDomainName` which I was hoping to avoid.  Is this how you understand it?  If that's what's required I can generate that serverside...I just want to make sure it's right I guess!

Comment: No, in that case you should read this article:
http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55503

Also updated my main post.

Comment: I want to do the same thing as the author but I don't know where you mean to put this code? I'm doing the asychronos way ... ``var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   $(document).ready(function() {    
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', ...`` ? Where would I put this? ``_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none');`` ?

Comment: Also I want to do this because one domain is in English and the other in Swedish so it shouldn't be counted as duplicate

Comment: For the sake of those coming now to this answer, the links aren't working anymore. The current link is: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

Comment: is it possible to track 25 websites using a single code? I would like to know how many people visited each site without creating 25 websites separately..