# Duplicate domain tracking on Google Analytics issue

Tags: google-analytics

We've accidentally placed the same Google Analytics tracking code on two different domains. 
www.y.com
www.x.com

We've rectified the issue now but retrospectively, is there any way to filter that data going to the specific domain name www.x.com for example?

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Google Analytics: Track two domains as one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133880/google-analytics-track-two-domains-as-one)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a filter to the view (profile) in question. That will remove the data that you don't want.  Another option if you don't want to loose the data in the view would be to create a custom segment that you could use when ever you want to split the data out.

---

Update from [Google+](https://plus.google.com/117200475532672775346/posts/jdnk2LJ9tUC)

You can search with regex

^/app/

in the small search bar (custom segment) in your page reports (e.g. Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages), after which you can look at the aggregate metrics for all pages which start with /app/ (i.e. all the pages with different parameters).

If all the /app/.* have the same page title, you can look at the Behavior > Overview report, but choose Page Title as the dimension.

Comment: View filters will not work retrospectively (there is no way to reprocess historical data - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042405/google-analytics-how-to-merge-canonical-urls-for-historical-data). However segmentation (based on hostname) will do the trick.

Comment: The filters don't work from the look of things. Here's what I'm inputting: Exclude > Traffic to the hostname > that begin with > example.com <-- is that correct? It doesn't seem to exclude anything

Comment: That would be filter by hostname (the hostname field stores the domain name on which the page in question was hosted, so you can filter out the wrong hostname).

Comment: It's not retrospective unfortunately! Any other ideas?